# Transformation to show mean, st.dev from dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to show the mean and st deviation comparisons across groups while keeping the id, start, end and value columns in the output.

```
id  start       end         value

a   5/1/2020    6/1/2020    2
a   6/1/2020    7/1/2020    3
a   7/1/2020    8/1/2020    4
a   8/1/2020    9/1/2020    20
b   5/1/2020    6/1/2020    15
b   6/1/2020    7/1/2020    2
b   7/1/2020    8/1/2020    1
```

Desired output

```
id  start       end         value   mean    stdev       1SD       2SD     3SD

a   5/1/2020    6/1/2020    2                   
a   6/1/2020    7/1/2020    3                   
a   7/1/2020    8/1/2020    4                   
a   8/1/2020    9/1/2020    20      29      8.539126    20.5      12     -5.5
b   5/1/2020    6/1/2020    15                  
b   6/1/2020    7/1/2020    2                   
b   7/1/2020    8/1/2020    1       18      7.81025     10.2      2.4    -5.4
```

The desired output, groups the id, as well as the value and finds the
mean, standard deviation and the 1SD, 2SD, and 3SD

This is what I am doing:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

output = df.groupby('id')['value'].agg(['mean','std'])   

output['1SD'] = output['mean'] - output['std']              

output['2SD'] = output['mean'] - 2 *output['std']           

output['3SD'] = out['mean'] - 3 *output['std']
```

However, I was not able to retain the start, end and value columns. I am still researching and any
suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) here:

```
g = output.groupby('id')['value']
output['mean'] = g.transform('mean')   
output['std'] = g.transform('std')

output['1SD'] = output['mean'] - output['std']              
output['2SD'] = output['mean'] - 2 *output['std']           
output['3SD'] = out['mean'] - 3 *output['std']
```

If need only one row per group add [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for match only last duplicated rows:

```
mask = ~df['id'].duplicated(keep='last')
g = output.groupby('id')['value']
output.loc[mask, 'mean'] = g.transform('mean')   
output.loc[mask, 'std'] = g.transform('std')

output['1SD'] = output['mean'] - output['std']              
output['2SD'] = output['mean'] - 2 *output['std']           
output['3SD'] = output['mean'] - 3 *output['std']    

print (output)
  id     start       end  value  mean       std       1SD       2SD        3SD
0  a  5/1/2020  6/1/2020      2   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
1  a  6/1/2020  7/1/2020      3   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
2  a  7/1/2020  8/1/2020      4   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
3  a  8/1/2020  9/1/2020     20  7.25  8.539126 -1.289126 -9.828251 -18.367377
4  b  5/1/2020  6/1/2020     15   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
5  b  6/1/2020  7/1/2020      2   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
6  b  7/1/2020  8/1/2020      1  6.00  7.810250 -1.810250 -9.620499 -17.430749
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael I will try this. Could you explain what the ‘mask’ does?

Comment: @Lynnette - It assign rows only for last row per groups, if omit it get repeated all values per groups, in another words no NaNs like in second solution.